# ¿Cómo volver a mostrar menú tras elegir opción errónea en java?

Tags: java, menú

El caso es que si la opción que se añade es un número erróneo si muestra un mensaje y vuelve a pedir opción, pero no se como implementarlo para que si se añade un carácter como opción vuelva a pedir una opción en vez de "petar".

Os dejo el código en cuestión:

```
do {
    System.out.println("\n         ----PROGRAMA ATLAS----");
    System.out.print("");
    System.out.println("----Porfavor seleccione una opción:----");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("    1. Añadir una entrada al atlas      2. Mostrar el contenido actual del atlas");
    System.out.println("    3. Buscar una entrada del atlas     4. Modificar una entrada del atlas");
    System.out.println("    5. Eliminar una entrada del atlas   6. Eliminar el contenido completo del atlas");
    System.out.println("    7. Salir\n");
    System.out.print("Teclea una de las opciones: ");
    seleccion = entrada.nextInt();

    if (seleccion >= 1 && seleccion <= 7) {
        bandera = 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Debes teclear un número entero.");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
    }
} while (bandera == 0);
```

Tanto la variable bandera como selección están inicializadas a 0.

Comment: Cambia `seleccion=entrada.nextInt()` por `seleccion=entrada.next()` o `nextLine()`. Estos métodos de la clase Scanner admiten cualquier caracter

Comment: gracias chaval todo arreglado :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como comenta Miguel27 en el comentario, además de cambiar el tipo de dato que lees, luego, antes de comprobar si es mayor que 0 y menor que 8, debes comprobar que lo que leíste, sea numérico.

En el siguiente enlace, tienes varias formas de comprobarlo:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558206/how-can-i-check-if-a-value-is-of-type-integer

Answer (score 0):

en seleccion pon `seleccion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());`
si pones nextint te lee la linea pero sigues en la misma no produce salto de linea
si parseas el nextline lee la linea como numerica y ademas hace el sato de linea.

Comment: Agregale una explicacion breve aunque sea.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes capturar con un `try catch` la excepción que lanza a la hora de introducir un caracter en `seleccion = entrada.nextInt();` para mostrar el mensaje que quieras, junto a ello utilizar una variable `boolean` para después determinar si has introducido un carácter y no un numero.

**Try catch:**

```
try {

    seleccion = entrada.nextInt();

} catch (InputMismatchException e) {

    System.out.println("Debes teclear un número entero.");
    entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    check = true;
}
```

**Comprobación:**

```
if (seleccion == (int) seleccion) { // comprobamos que el buffer contiene 
                                    //un numero entero para cambiar el check a false
    check = false;
}
```

**Ejemplo completo:**

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int seleccion = 0;
        boolean check = false;

        do {

            System.out.println("\n         ----PROGRAMA ATLAS----");
            System.out.print("");
            System.out.println("----Porfavor seleccione una opción:----");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("    1. Añadir una entrada al atlas      2. Mostrar el contenido actual del atlas");
            System.out.println("    3. Buscar una entrada del atlas     4. Modificar una entrada del atlas");
            System.out.println("    5. Eliminar una entrada del atlas   6. Eliminar el contenido completo del atlas");
            System.out.println("    7. Salir\n");
            System.out.print("Teclea una de las opciones: ");

            try {

                seleccion = entrada.nextInt();

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                System.out.println("Debes teclear un número entero.");
                entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
                check = true;
            }

            if (seleccion == (int) seleccion) { // comprobamos que el buffer contiene un numero entero para cambiar el
                                            // check a false
                check = false;
            } 

        } while ((seleccion < 1 || seleccion > 7) || check);
    }
}
```